# How to import jmh in IDEA(JDK15)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jmh

how to config the jmh in IDEA

the tutorial I followed: https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness

I use the JDK 15 ,after I import relative dependency
[image]

still got a error

[image]
But I heard that after jdk12, jmh has been integrated into jdk. How to fix this ,or recommend me another tutorial,thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pasted the dependencies into the wrong section. You need to crate `dependencies` tag and paste the dependencies there:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.28</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
  <version>1.28</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then **Reload** the project in Maven tool window.